# how to give space after the 2nd column of 4 grid columns?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have tried like this. but I need to give space vertically at the middle only in between 2nd and 3rd column. How to do that?

```css
.grid-container{
    background: #999999;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 10px;
    height: 500px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 80px 80px 80px 80px;
    grid-template-rows: 80px 80px 80px;
    grid-column-gap: 10px;
    grid-row-gap: 10px;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.item{
    border: 1px solid rgb(20, 118, 184);
    font-size: 18px;
    display: grid;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
        <div class="item">A1</div>
        <div class="item">A2</div>
        <div class="item">A3</div>
        <div class="item">A4</div>
        <div class="item">A5</div>
        <div class="item">A6</div>
        <div class="item item11">A7</div>
        <div class="item item22">A8</div>
        <div class="item">A9</div>
        <div class="item">A10</div>
        <div class="item">A11</div>
        <div class="item">A12</div>
    </div>
```

How can I give a at the middle vertically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add an extra empty column:

```css
.grid-container{
    background: #999999;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 10px;
    height: 500px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 80px 80px 10px 80px 80px; /* added a column in the middle */
    grid-template-rows: 80px 80px 80px;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    grid-auto-flow:dense; /* to make sure we fill all the spaces*/
}
.item{
    border: 1px solid rgb(20, 118, 184);
    font-size: 18px;
    display: grid;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

/* the pseudo element will take the new column added */
.grid-container::before {
  content:"";
  grid-column:3;
  grid-row:span 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
        <div class="item">A1</div>
        <div class="item">A2</div>
        <div class="item">A3</div>
        <div class="item">A4</div>
        <div class="item">A5</div>
        <div class="item">A6</div>
        <div class="item item11">A7</div>
        <div class="item item22">A8</div>
        <div class="item">A9</div>
        <div class="item">A10</div>
        <div class="item">A11</div>
        <div class="item">A12</div>
    </div>
```

Also like below without pseudo element:

```css
.grid-container{
    background: #999999;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 10px;
    height: 500px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 80px 80px 10px 80px 80px; /* added a column in the middle */
    grid-template-rows: 80px 80px 80px;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.item{
    border: 1px solid rgb(20, 118, 184);
    font-size: 18px;
    display: grid;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.item:nth-child(4n + 3) {
  grid-column:4; /* jump the middle column */
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
        <div class="item">A1</div>
        <div class="item">A2</div>
        <div class="item">A3</div>
        <div class="item">A4</div>
        <div class="item">A5</div>
        <div class="item">A6</div>
        <div class="item item11">A7</div>
        <div class="item item22">A8</div>
        <div class="item">A9</div>
        <div class="item">A10</div>
        <div class="item">A11</div>
        <div class="item">A12</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Interesting solution. However my concern is, that it does not work with infinite ammounts of content. So if we add more boxes, the grid will be messed up without adjusting the span. Is there a solution for it aswell possibly with the use of `nth-child(5n+3)`?

Comment: @tacoshy yes you can use nth-child (check the update) but I considered the fact that he has a definite grid (considering his template rows and columns)

Comment: ah thank you. I'm aware that his `template-rows` indicate a definite grid. But I also using questions and solution to gatehr experience and try to find uses for other cases. So in other simliar cases, the grid might not be definite and your anwser will still be useful for those other cases.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution. I've given as a definite grid but it can be a dynamic grid as well. What to do then? Every time I need the gap right at the middle. It can have a 4, 6, 8 or 10 columns.

Comment: @ASAD well, it depends. I gave an answer based on the code you provided. For a dynamic grid I may do something else. You can edit your question to include this factor and add more details if you want accurate answers